# how to create a inverse like cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need create a inverse like query, something like this

```
SELECT * FROM identities where 'keyword' like concat('%',identities.name,'%')
```

keyword = something the user type

identities.name = the table column

but I neet to create using a cakephp syntax

```php
$this->Indentity->find('all', array('conditions' => array('here something to help me'));
```

a normal LIKE using cakephp not working because i neet inverse like

this query not working because is normal LIKE

```php
$this->Indentity->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Indentity.name LIKE' => $keyword));
```

this query not working to because concat('%',`identities`.`name`,'%') uses like string not a function

```php
$this->Indentity->find('all', array('conditions' => array($keyword . ' LIKE' => "concat('%',`identities`.`name`,'%')"));
```

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. I suspect you are using CakePHP2.5.

Answer (score 0):

a) You can always use virtual fields for such specific querys

b) In this case it is probably easiest to just write it in a single row:

```
$conditions = array($keyword . " LIKE CONCAT('%', `identities`.`name`, '%')";
$result = $this->Indentity->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Note the missing `=>` key value operator in this case to signalize the ORM to not escape the statement.

NOTE: Bear in mind that you will have to manually secure (escape, sanitize, ...) the input in a way that people cannot injection vulerabilities into the query, e.g. using the datasources value() method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that without an example showing how to escape manually, 99% of people using this snippet will introduce an SQL injection vulerability into their apps, people are lazy ass bi***es, they won't read the docs unless you ram them down their throats :)